# XSl Smart search and replace

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to do a find and replace to the attributes of a xml element?  I want to change the directory that is being pointed to by a href:

From:

```
<image href="./views/screenshots/page1.png">
```

to

```
<image href="screenshots/page1.png">
```

And from:

```
<image href="./screenshots/page2.png">
```

to

```
<image href="screenshots/page2.png">
```

So by getting rid of all "./" that belong to the href of all image tags, but only the image tags. And furthermore, get rid of first folder if it is not named "screenshots".  Is there a simple way to do this in one go?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="image/@href[starts-with(.,'./screenshots/')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
   "image/@href
     [starts-with(.,'./')
     and not(starts-with(substring(.,3), 'screenshots/'))
     ]">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring(.,3),'/')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template priority="10"
      match="image/@href[starts-with(.,'./views/')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,9)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
   <t>
    <image href="./views/screenshots/page1.png"/>
    <image href="./screenshots/page2.png"/>
    <load href="./xxx.yyy"/>
    <image href="ZZZ/screenshots/page1.png"/>
   </t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<t>
    <image href="screenshots/page1.png"/>
    <image href="screenshots/page2.png"/>
    <load href="./xxx.yyy"/>
    <image href="ZZZ/screenshots/page1.png"/>
</t>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use and overriding of the identity rule**. This is the most fundamental and most powerful XSLT design pattern.
2. **Only `href` attributes of `image` elements are modified**.
3. **Only `href` attributes that start with the string `"./"` or the string `"./{something-different-than-screenshots}/"` are processed in a special way** (by separate templates).
4. **All other nodes are only processed by the identity template**.
5. **This is a pure "push style" solution**.

Comment: Yes this is close to what I need, but how do remove the "./views/" when it crops up, but only when folder is "views"?

Comment: @Ace: You need to rephrase your question. At present it is asking for "getting rid of all "./" that belong to the href of all image tags, but only the image tags". Could you specify the new requirement clearly?

Comment: Added description that preceding folder sometimes need to be reomved

Comment: @Ace: There is contradiction in your new text: "subFolder" is not "screenshots" but you show it not-removed in the results. Please, correct.

Comment: @Ace: I edited your question so that now there is no mismatch between the requirements and the stated wanted result. Please, verify this is correct. I also edited my answer and it now contains a solution that solves exactly the newly-formulated problem. Is everything OK now?

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion, even in the mis-edits.  The question has been fixed again, so it should be perfect now.  Thanks for you patience.

Comment: Yes!  The solutions works.  Just out of curiosity (since this might come up in the future).  I noticed that you solution checks for 'views', what if I want to remove any './' and all preceding folders up and until 'screenhots'?

Comment: @Ace: THere is still something undefined in your question. If you have: `./a/b/screenshots/c/screenshots/page1.png` -- what should be the result? When you definr this explicitly, it would be good to ask a new question.

Comment: question reposted on "XSL: removing preceding folders on image path"